# What EL version should I use along with JSF 2.1.29-01?

Tags: maven, jsf, jsf-2, el

When we were using JSF 1.2-09 we had the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>el-impl</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But now, we're updating to the JSF 2.1.29-01 and it's not clear what version I should use by now?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1) information, `JSF 2.1` depends on `el-api 1.0`.

Comment: So it's even not neccesary to include that dependency, isn't it?

Comment: I think Maven won't fetch it through jsf dependency, you'll have to include it yourself.

Comment: But what about EL2? Can I start using it with JSF 2.1?

Comment: Sure, `1.0` is just the minimum required version.

Comment: Just checked, if you are using Tomcat - `el-api 2.2` is included in Tomcat 7 distribution, so you can include the dependency with `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Answer (score 1):

The EL implementation as well as the el-api jar you are using is part of your application container distribution. As JSF 2.0/2.1 is part of the [Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee6technologies-1955512.html) technology stack which is implemented by Tomcat 7, you should link to that api spec.

To compile your sources you will need to reference the needed el-api 2.2 with `<scope>provided</scope>` in your pom so that your web archive will not contain any EL libraries and possible conflicts with container provided libraries are avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum requirements from the JSF [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info):

> JSF 2.1 uses some Servlet 3.0 specific features, but is backwards
>   compatible with Servlet 2.5. Those Servlet 3.0 features are optional.

And if we take a look to the JSF 2.0 minimum requirements we can find that:  **EL 2.1 which goes hand in hand with Servlet 2.5**

So the conclusion is that EL 2.1 is *the recommended* EL for JSF 2.1